# <input type=‘file’> for IE gives full path, need file name only

Tags: file, upload, input, path, internet-explorer

When perform uploading from IE browser, that my backend(org.apache.commons.fileupload) gets full file path.

For other non-IE browsers it gets filename and it's OK because of security.

How to get ***filename*** only from input for IE?

Is it possible to do on UI, because I think it's not very graceful to edit apache lib.

Maybe , some parameter exists for input field?

I can do it on server, but interested in UI approach.

Comment: Hi.. please change Alex'answer to the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, apm,why? Quentin's answer was OK for me.

Comment: Sorry, I thought if you select alex's answer as correct that may be helpful for others, who is looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The point of the file input is to provide a *file*. Names that come with it are "whatever the browser vendor feels like using", they aren't guaranteed to have anything to do with the file name on the file system at all.

You can't change what the browser sends.

If you are going to make use of the name sent by the browser, then you **need** to make sure it is valid for whatever you are going to do with it (e.g. make sure it only includes characters that are allowed in filenames on your filesystem). This makes it something that must be handled on the server (just like any other client supplied data).

Comment: ok,thanks, seems that server solution is accepted only, i just read apache advises:http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html#whole-path-from-IE

Answer (score 53):

There is also an IE option under:

- Internet Options
- Security tab
- In "Internet" or "Intranet" click on Custom Level
- In the Security Settings scroll down until you see “Include local directory path when uploading files to a server” and disable it.
- Click OK on Internet Options window and refresh.

Comment: Somewhat official reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 38):

Try this at the server side:

```
Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
```

Answer (score 27):

There is actually a pretty easy workaround if you are uploading with FormData via Xhr.  The [FormData.append api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) allows for you to pass in the filename as the 3rd argument.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
//explicitly setting the file name works in IE 11
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
```

Comment: This is the simplest example. As far as the concern of front end being not able to send the correct name, this should be done at front end level instead of working on back end. Besides, I also wanted to show name in a files list so this was the perfect choice.

Answer (score 3):

You are interested in a UI approach.
You could add a hidden input-field (or JSON entry) that contains just the bare file-name, populated by javascript.

Using the following cross-browser<sup>(including IE)</sup>/platform javascript function (taken from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/588079), with full explanation and reference), which gets the filename only:

```js
function extractFilename(s){ 
  // returns string containing everything from the end of the string 
  //   that is not a back/forward slash or an empty string on error
  //   so one can check if return_value===''
  return (typeof s==='string' && (s=s.match(/[^\\\/]+$/)) && s[0]) || '';
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="alert(extractFilename(this.value));">
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like easy to handle this from server side but based on the requirements.

I have  tested this in production env and works fine.

```
String fileName = file.getName();
if (fileName != null) {
    fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileName);
}
```

IE by defaults gives the full path along with the file name, and it causes issue while uploading a file from some shared directory. adding above snippet will resolve the issue and works well in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

if you post by xhr then you can simply provide the file name

[image: post look like this]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.