# File names with the full paths

Tags: fine-uploader

Some clients report that after uploading the files with fine-uploader they see the full path (e.g. C:\Temp\file.txt instead of file.txt). It is not the desired behavior, moreover I could never reproduce it on my working environment with the same version of software. 
I guess it is something to do with the browser settings but cannot figure out which ones.
What is the way to disable such a behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<input type=‘file’> for IE gives full path, need file name only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200100/input-type-file-for-ie-gives-full-path-need-file-name-only)

Answer (score 1):

You will get this behavior with Internet Explorer set to the Medium security level, or a custom level with "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" enabled.