# Asp.Net Mvc: How to get uploaded file actual path

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using HTML input file to select the file. I have tried in JQUERY but I it returns fake path.

```
$("#inputfile").val()
```

I want to get selected file actual path e.g

> D:\Documents\image.png

So I have tried to upload the file in ASP.NET MVC and check the path but It also gives file name.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFileName() {
    var result = "";

    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        result = Request.Files[0].FileName;
    }

    return Json(result);
}
```

Is there any solution to get the path. I know this a browser security feature but I have to entertain the client requirement. Please suggest the solution if exist.

Thank you

Comment: what the reason, do you need this?

Comment: you cannot get the actual file path only the file name. have a look at this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-Full-Path-from-FileUpload-control-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I have read many articles but got same answer "No Way" :)

Comment: User wants to save documents path in a XML file.

Comment: Why? Maybe, they have another problem and they try to solve just an effect of it

Comment: You can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no way.

You cannot get the client's file path, only the filename.

Comment: Actually, you can in [old versions of Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20688629/636942).