# Filename only in django form field

Tags: python, django

I have a model that contains a filefield and am using a modelform to add instances. When I come to modify an instance the form shows the current file and displays the file path ie library/filename.

Is there a way to show just the filename in the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got around this by using javascript.

I added the following to my model..

```
def filename(self):
    return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

Then added this into my javascript in my template

```
{% block javascript %}
<script>

{% if part.file %}
$('[href="{{ part.file.url }}"]').html("{{ part.filename }}");
{% endif %}

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This changed the link to show just the filename

Answer (score 0):

A `FileField` will use by default the `FileInput` widget that produces a `<input type="file">` HTML tag. I don't think you can change the default "display full path" behaviour from Django, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200100/input-type-file-for-ie-gives-full-path-need-file-name-only).

However, you can customise things in your `ModelForm` like that:

```
class YourForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        ...
        widgets = {
            'your_file_attribute': FileInput(attrs={'html_attribute': value}),
        }
```