# CreateUploadSession() fails on request from IE11 and Edge

Tags: c#, .net

Error message:
Code: BadRequest Message: Found a function 'microsoft.graph.createUploadSession' on an open property. Functions on open properties are not supported. Inner error.

I am confused as to what it's referring to as 'open property'.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out IE and Edge post files with the filenames being the fullpath to the file, which is the reason why the post to Microsoft.Graph failed with the above error message.

If you're sending your files via FormData, here's a quick fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/45066287/11504672