# PrimeFaces 6.1 - UploadedFile problem with getFileName

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 6.1 in my prject and implemented UploadedFile as described in [PrimeFaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml) and evreything works fine (I can upload and download the file as I wish) except the fileName.

e.g. when I try to upload the file from following path :

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\test.txt
```

and in Java code I try to get the fileName as follow:

```
FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
```

the uploadedFile.getName() returns this string "C:UsersmeDocumentstest.txt"
The whole path with out "" included drive Name!
I did not override any classes and I did not change any functionality as well!

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix it?

regards
Sara

Comment: Can you post the code of your page(xhtml + view + model)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<input type=‘file’> for IE gives full path, need file name only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200100/input-type-file-for-ie-gives-full-path-need-file-name-only)

Comment: Thank you so Mach it was the problem .... the IE returns the full path however the Firefox and chrome return only the file name. @Jasper de Vries